How to apply modifier to expression
I have an XML file, here is a snippet:
<response>
  <data offset="4" length="2" pattern="[%lx]" desc="Hours"/>
  <data offset="2" length="2" pattern="[%lx]" desc="Minutes"/>
  <data offset="0" length="2" pattern="[%lx]" desc="Seconds"/>
  <data offset="6" length="2" pattern="[%lx]" desc="Day"/>
  <data offset="8" length="2" pattern="[%lx]" desc="Month"/>
  <data offset="10" length="2" pattern="[%lx]" desc="Year" modifier="+2020"/>
</response>

This is used to decode a response in code which is the time and date, the year is returned in the response as 04, I want to apply the modifier to this value, I'm trying to keep it as flexible and generic as possible.
How can I take the value of the modifier which I have in code as a string and apply it to the value? My code:
double dblData = 0.0;
if (double.TryParse(strData, out dblData) == true) {
...
}

strData is a string which in this case contains 04, how can I apply the modifier which I have in another variable called strModifier to strData so it becomes 04+2020 and the result is 2024?
Can I do this with Lambda?
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022, version 17.11.3, the project is using the Target framework .NET Framework 4.8, Output type Windows Application.
I am having problems trying out the suggestions because I cannot add Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting, I've also tried the other suggested answer but the code will not compile.

how complicated can strModifier be? Like *5? -6? And why is it a string?

I think you misinterpret the function of lambda, it's not a formula parser.

@Magnus, I have modifier the attribute from "+2020" to "+,2020", the code will split the value so the arithmetic opcode is the first field and the second the value to apply, its a string because its an XML attribute.

@shingo, I'll settle for anyway to do what I want, do you have an alternative?

I found this post:
Is there an eval function In C#?
And based on the answer posted by rezo-megrelidze:
if (cdmProvider == null) {
    cdmProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
}
if (cdmProvider != null) {
    string strModifier = detail.strModifier;
    strModifier = strModifier.Replace(mcstrValue, strData);
    CompilerResults results = cdmProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(
        new CompilerParameters()
      , new string[] {                                                                    
        string.Format(@"namespace nsILC {{
            public class clsILC {{
                public double Eval() {{
                    return {0};
                }}
            }}", strModifier)
        });
Assembly test = results.CompiledAssembly;
dynamic evalulator = Activator.CreateInstance(test.GetType("nsILC.clsILC"));
Console.WriteLine(evalulator.Eval());                                                    

Works a treat, in the console I can see the correct result.

Would you not run into memory issues dynamically loading assemblies into memory?

@Magnus, haven't observed any problems yet.

You could try this code. As I saw, the value of modifier could be also +,2020, so here's generic approach to account also for that (explanations in code):
static double Parse(string strData, string modifier)
{
    // Parse strData to number
    var @double = double.Parse(strData);
    // Extract operation to perform from first character.
    var operation = modifier[0];
    // Apply regex to capture all numbers:
    // it just captures consecutive digits
    // and parses to number.
    var numbers = Regex.Matches(modifier.Substring(1), @"\d+")
        .Select(x => double.Parse(x.Value))
        .ToArray();
    // Apply operation based on extracted information.
    // Also, if you are sure there will be always one number,
    // you can use numbers[0] instead of numbers.Sum()
    return operation switch
    {
        '+' =>  @double + numbers.Sum(),
        //'-' =>  @double - numbers.Sum(),
        //'*' =>  @double * numbers.Sum(),
        _ => throw new NotSupportedException(),
    };
}

Now it can be used as below. Both examples return 2024:
var result1 = Parse("04", "+2020");
var result2 = Parse("04", "+,2020");


Thank you, will take a look at this now.

I'm having difficulty with the code as it is above, for example [1..] is that supposed to be like that because it doesn't like it in MSVC ?  Without the .. the Select is underlined in red, MatchCollection does not contain a definition for Select...

@SPlatten see update.

Sorry, I don't understand what your edit means, it doesn't look correct, modifier is an array, not a string, so why not just modifier[1] ?

Please see edit to original post.

Not sure what you mean, I assumed that modifier is just string, like "+2024" or "+,2024" - can it be different?

Correct, modifier is a string, can you edit your answer with code that will compile?

@SPlatten Done - I used Substring instead of ranges.

using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strData = "04";
        string strModifier = "+2020";

        int result = (int) await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(strData + strModifier);
    } 
}


I am working with Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022, I don't seem to have Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.

You have to install package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting

Tried following the instructions from a console in the project folder, getting "The project does not support adding package references through the add package command.", if I try to install from with VisualStudio, what is it I need to look for because "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" doesn't return anything.

Right click on the "Dependencies" below the project, click "Manage nuget packes" and than search for "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting" and install it.

I'm looking in the Solution Explorer, I don't see Dependencies ?

If you are on .net old, it is called "references"

thank you, I see "Manage NuGet Packages..." but its grey out.

Try stopping debug

ok in the Browse text box, if I enter Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, "No pacakages found" is shown, edit, if I just enter CodeAnalysis then it comes up...installing now.

please see edit to original post.

Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting targets .net standard 2.0 so should work with net48

what can I say, it doesn't appear to work on my set-up.
